# load custom view in MBProgressHUD

Tags: uiview, xib, mbprogresshud, custom-view

Is it possible to load a custom view in MBProgressHUD overlay, there is a custom view option with the MBProgressHUD class, but can i assign a XIB view etc with customView??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes you could do something like this:

```
MBProgressHUD *loadingHUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] init];
loadingHUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeCustomView;
loadingHUD.labelText = nil;
loadingHUD.detailsLabelText = nil;
UIView *customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds]; // Set a size
// Add stuff to view here
loadingHUD.customView = customView;
[HUD show:YES];
```

Comment: I think you should add the init line of `MBProgressHUD`.

Comment: Did not add hud view to parent view